# Can't pipe split_view over a string into transform(to<string>)

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, range-v3

(Including both [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) just in case the solution/workaround is different.)

The code below works,

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <range/v3/algorithm/equal.hpp>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/split.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace ranges;
using namespace ranges::views;

int main() {

    auto to_string =
#if 0
        to<std::string>
#else
        [](auto x){ return to<std::string>(x); }
#endif
        ;
    std::string str{"hello world"};

    auto strs = str | split(' ');

    assert(to_string(*strs.begin()) == "hello");
    assert(equal(str | split(' ') | transform(to_string),
                std::vector{"hello", "world"}));
}
```

but switching the `0` to `1` in the `#if` branch makes it fail.

What is the lambda doing differently than the `to<std::string>` object itself?

Comment: #if 0 branch should be `to<std::string>()` (note the extra parentheses)

Comment: @康桓瑋, I see now, from [conversion.hpp](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/range/conversion.hpp), that [`to_vector` is an object](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/21b70bee785cabd3ca5e3da173bf3bdbb9df1344/include/range/v3/range/conversion.hpp#L399-L400) whereas [`to` is a set of overloads](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/21b70bee785cabd3ca5e3da173bf3bdbb9df1344/include/range/v3/range/conversion.hpp#L403-L470). But then I don't understand how something like `rangeOfChars | to<std::string>` can be valid, as the second operand to `|`...

Comment: ... is not an object but an overload set. I can even just write `auto to_string = to<std::string>;`, but how is the overload resolved, if I'm not passing any arguments to `to<std::string>`, given it is an overloaded set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the lambda doing differently than the `to<std::string>` object
> itself?

`to<std::string>` is *not* an object, it is actually an instantiated *function pointer*, which takes a default-constructible tag and returns a closure object that records the specified container type (i.e. `std::string` in your example).

So its type can be roughly spelled as

```
/* some range adaptor closure type */ (*)(tag_t)
```

To make `r | to<std::string>` work, range-v3 additionally defines a pipe operator inside the `tag_t` that accepts this function pointer type, roughly as follows:

```
struct tag_t
{
  friend Container
  operator|(R&& r, /* some range adaptor closure type */ (*)(tag_t)) {
    return /* Immediately default-constructs and invokes a callable object */
  }
};
```

In your example, when the `#if 0` branch is enabled, `to_string` is a function pointer that receives `tag_t`. This is why you get an error when invoking `to_string(*strs.begin())`, because `*strs.begin()` returns a range, which cannot be converted to `tag_t`.

To make the above work, you can use `to<std::string>()`（note the parentheses here）to get a range adaptor closure object directly.

---

It is worth noting that C++23 `std::ranges::to` does *not* currently support the syntax for omitting parentheses. The standards committee has discussed whether to support this feature (see [issues/527](https://github.com/cplusplus/nbballot/issues/527)), but unfortunately, it was rejected recently.

Comment: But from [here](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/21b70bee785cabd3ca5e3da173bf3bdbb9df1344/include/range/v3/range/conversion.hpp#L403-L470) it looks to me that `to` is an overloaded and templated name, so `to<std::string>` could in general still be a name referring to more than one function, in which case I don't think it could decay to a pointer could it? (I'm assuming when you write "`to<std::string>` is [...]  a _function pointer_" you mean that it decays to a pointer when passed to the `operator|` you mention. Am I correct?)

Comment: If you look closely at those overloads, `to<std::string>` only references one valid template function, which is [this one](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/21b70bee785cabd3ca5e3da173bf3bdbb9df1344/include/range/v3/range/conversion.hpp#L427), since it only has one template parameter.